# Why does Virgin Trains need two addresses?

Tags: uk, trains, bookings

I'm trying to book train tickets from Virgin Trains (England) and need to register an account to do so.
The account regristration requires "two address lines". What does this mean? I only have one address just like many of us, I assume.

[image]

The only accurate filled in information above is the country. The error was thrown when I filled in my actual address and postcode.

Comment: Probably you are supposed to put your city on the second line?

Comment: Wow, that's a really badly designed form... It's like they took what each field was named in the database and thought "Meh, that'll do"

Comment: @user568458 They probably don't know about User Experience SE...

Comment: @user568458 I just registered a Eurostar account as well and they had multiple lines as well but at least the additional ones were indicated as optional.

Comment: In the UK, *theoretically* your address is uniquely identified by your postcode and your house number, but *practically* the postal service wouldn't be very happy with only that information. The practical minimum would be "House number and street name", "Town name", "Postcode". For small communities you would usually have an extra line i.e. "House no & steet", "Village name", "name of nearest large town"

Comment: @user568458 It may be a well-designed form *for UK addresses*, because there is an easily accessible national postal data base, and when you enter your postcode most of the following lines might be filled automatically. That is also a good check that you typed the correct post code. Whether Virgin know about similar databases for every possible foreign country is another matter, though.

Comment: Maybe they thought Erwin Schrödinger was still alive?

Comment: Could be worse they could be labelled "Building Number", "Building Name", "Principle Street", "Dependant Locality", "Post Town" and "Post Code" (which could be further split into "Outcode and Incode") which would be accurate but not very clear to people in the UK either!

Comment: @alephzero: I have a friend who successfully received mail addressed to <his given name> // Jesus // Oxford. Good old Royal Mail, although this was in the days when they still were royal.

Comment: Better than the train company I once bought from (First Great Western, I think), which allowed you to select any country, but nonetheless always required a UK-format postcode. (I live in Ireland, which at the time did not have postcodes at all outside of Dublin.)

Comment: @SteveJessop. http://www.thejournal.ie/me-versus-an-post-2143603-Jun2015/

Comment: @alephzero I once worked at a company located right on a major intercity road where the extact street address (so street and house number) could also be found in the next town, which also was a suburb of the town the company was located in. About once a week we got visitors and mail for the owners of the other address. And this WAS with a (slightly) different postcode.

Comment: From a UX perspective, all the need to do to make that form much easier is change the field captions to "Address line 1", "Address line 2", etc. Adding the word "line" would entirely remove the confusion that led to this question being asked.

Comment: These problems are frequent with trying to force addresses that are valid in country A into a website in country B. This is quite minor compared to my hassle in the UK ordering goods from Germany. This in turn may be trivial compared to a Japanese, Chinese, Thai or Sri Lankan trying to put his address into an European website. Or vice versa. Please, website designers, accept that for foreign customers at least, whatever strings of incomprehensible unicode that are put in an address field are valid where the customer comes from. Your only responsibility should be to reproduce them faithfully. D

Comment: @SteveJessop How?

Comment: @Fiksdal: The expectation of the person who sent it was: first, there's only one Oxford in the UK. Once the letter reaches the Oxford sorting office, there's only one "Jesus College" in Oxford, and it's quite common to refer to the colleges without the word "College". Once the letter reached the college, my friend was the only person there with that given name, so the porter (which is what Oxford calls the gatekeeper / general reception office) put the letter in his pigeon-hole.

Comment: @SteveJessop Haha, nice.

Comment: @SteveJessop When I was like five or six, I wrote a letter to my grandpa, who lived in a tiny village across the country. On the envelope, I simply wrote "Bestefar i Bud" which means "Grandpa in Bud" "Bud" is the name of the village. I didn't use a stamp, I just put it in the mailbox. It arrived! Presumably the guys at the post office found "Bud" in the list of towns. And since my grandpa's village is a place where everybody knows everybody, the postman  there probably saw the stamp and knew who had grandkids in that region. I'm assuming my grandpa paid the postage. Fun story.

Comment: @alephzero Two (or more) streets can use the same post code, so the building number is not quite sufficient. In some more rural areas a single post code may cover an entire hamlet. For an example, try DE4 4HA at http://www.royalmail.com/find-a-postcode ;)

Comment: @alephzero Houise number and post code is not unique - I have same number as another flat and have the same postcode. Local authority could not find me - unfortunately the rates people did

Comment: You need to buy a second property before to board this train

Answer (score 50, accepted):

These fields aren't for separate addresses; they are for different parts of one address. For example, in the second field you could write "Sesame Town".

Comment: Sesame town would be Address 3 in Australia, Sesame Suburb would be 2.

Comment: @Scott: for the information of non-British people, UK addresses are not so rigidly organised as Australian. The Post Office no longer encourages people to use suburbs, and pretty much any address can be written as <number> <street> // <postal town> // <postcode>. But some people like to include one or even two suburbs/villages, some people have a house name they put before the number/street, and of course some people need a flat or sub-building number before the number/street. Few British people would use all 5 address lines on that form.

Comment: Oh yeah, and it's still really common to put in the county for addresses outside London/Birmingham/Manchester. AFAIK it's completely ignored as long as there's a postal town or postcode.

Comment: For a while my (UK) address was <housename> // <village> // <postal town> // <postcode>.  You wouldn't believe how many forms require a house number, or a street name, or how many people on the phone couldn't understand that my street didn't have a name. And don't get me started on having a telephone number that begins with a six-digit area code! (including the zero)

Comment: @SteveJessop It's a good information doubling in case of an error. But of course, there are places where you could probably deliver from all around the world in one line, like: "THE PALACE OF WESTMINSTER" :D

Comment: @SteveJessop no you can't assume that - my address is <number> building name // street // postal town // postcode . For other issues see https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/

Comment: Assume what? Obviously it would be a mistake to write a form that only accepts "pretty much any address" and not "every address". As far as postal delivery is concerned, the significant part of the address is the postcode together with some information to indicate what box to put the mail in (which could be the name of number of a building, or might be more fine-grained than that). And regardless of formal postal address, people might want extra lines to help route the mail internally, after it's delivered. So assume nothing.

Comment: Anyway I wasn't trying to write a complete BNF for UK postal addresses. My point was that Scott's statement that line 2 of an Australian address is a suburb and line 3 is a town, *really really* doesn't apply to the UK. In some cases line 3 will still be the street. Once you know that it's pretty understandable why web developers customarily just give you some numbered lines to work with.

Comment: In the Netherlands, you will never add a suburb to the address, nor the postal area. All you do is your name, street name and house number, postcode and town name, (although the mail does recognize post codes if on the wrong line, like below the town name.)  Add NL before the post code and you do not even need the country name.

Comment: @Willeke: I'm impressed that post offices worldwide will recognise that format, without having to write "Netherlands" at the end. After all they must also encounter letters where the first two letters on the second-to-last line *aren't* a 2-letter country code. So nearly every postal worker in every small town in the world must know how to interpret that country-augmented postcode line.

Comment: @SteveJessop - five lines might be at least one too few! CompanyName // Unit 34 // XYZ Business Park // Somewhere Road // Village // Post-Town. I actually work at such an address. If it were a large company, a department name might also be needed for the internal post, especially if the company employed two John Smiths.

Comment: @nigel222: true. In practice I'm pretty sure in the UK that'd get delivered if you put the unit+business park on a single line or the road+village on a single line, provided you supply the correct postcode. So it's up to the web designer at what point to make the user decide how to write their address. Dunno about Virgin Trains, but in many cases there's no point taking more lines of address than your delivery service will let you print on a parcel label...

Comment: @SteveJessop of course. Have had to use commas many times. It gets more interesting when the web-site is in Germany with Google translate for assistance. I haven't yet had to order from outside the EU and USA.

Comment: @SteveJessop, the local post people do not recognize the post code / address information as a local one, so they know it is international. That will get it to the international mail sorting office, they regocnize the post code format, the first one or two letters of a post code are (as a rule) are nation, the next is the code within the country. If you send mail to F12500, it will get to that one French local sorting office, if it is to B4000 it will get to one Belgium one.

Comment: @Willeke: so if I write my address with the post code as "GB OX <the rest of my post code>", and shove it in a mail box in rural China, will it make it home to Oxford, UK? Or is it only certain countries that have this defined for their post codes?

Comment: I have never tried it in rural China but I have heard it should work, your UK post code and house number (or name) will get it to your house, rather than the town as in France and Belgium.

Comment: It might even be that NL in front of the post code works better than 'Netherlands' as countryline. As the name for the Netherlands changes with the language. In France they call it Pays Bas, in China they will call it something else again, likely something I would not recognize as the name of my country.

Answer (score 0):

Working in software development, we do the same thing, though with a twist.
Offering your users an option to enter a free form address like that allows for them to enter addresses that don't fit the strict format otherwise required on forms.
We give our users the option to select whether the address they want to enter is a street address, a PO box, or free form, but having only a free form option might be enough for Virgin.

Comment: The question is asking "How do I fill in this form?" not "Why is this form designed the way it is?"